# Shared RxJS subject for bidirectional data binding in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a singleton service for app settings

```
class Setting {
  get foo() {
    return storage.get('foo');
  }

  set foo(val)
    storage.set('foo', val);
  }
}
```

that is bound in components' views as `setting.foo`.

Because `storage` calls may be costly and because it may be asynchronous, I would prefer to replace getter/setter with RxJS subject that could update and read `storage` whenever needed.

So I'm refactoring it to

```
class Setting {

  constructor() {
    this.fooSubject = new ReplaySubject(1);

    fooSubject.subscribe((val) => {
      storage.set('foo', val);
    });

    this.foo$ = this.fooSubject
    .map(() => storage.get('foo'))
    .publishReplay(1).refCount();
}
```

and using it like `setting.foo$ | async` and `setting.fooSubject.next(newFoo)`. It looks like costly `storage.get` calls are cached now.

There are two problems.

The first one is that both `fooSubject` subject and `foo$` observable should be publicly available to make this work, while a subject was chosen because it is supposed to be both an observable and an observer.

Can `foo$` be made to be a single Subject property of `Setting` service, so it could be subscribed with `subscribe(...)` and updated with `next(...)`?

The second one is that the code is still synchronous.

How can this case be treated for `storage.get` and `storage.set` that return promises?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was really easy to get a subject with side effects by extending `AnonymousSubject` (a class for `Subject.create(...)` factory). Resulting subject gets `destination` and `source` properties that hold original subject and observable.

```
class FooSharedSubject extends AnonymousSubject {
    constructor() {
        const subject = new BehaviorSubject('');

        const observable = subject.asObservable()
        .mergeMap((value) => promisedStorage.get('foo'))
        .publishReplay(1)
        .refCount();

        super(subject, observable);
    }

    next(value): void {
        promisedStorage.set('foo', value)).then(
            () => this.destination.next(value),
            () => this.destination.error(value)
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There's not much to suggest in your code when it actually works as you want. I'm not sure I catch your use case exactly but I think you can simplify your code by not using `this.foo$` at all.

The functionality of storing the latest value is provided by [`ReplaySubject`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/replaysubject.md) and unless you really need to call `storage.get('foo')` every time after `storage.set('foo', val);` it's not necessary.

I put your code into a live demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/pxjRQr6Q6Q7LzYb1oode?p=preview

So I think it can be simplified to this.

```
class Setting {

  constructor() {
    var storage = new Storage();

    this.fooSubject = new ReplaySubject(1);
    this.fooSubject.subscribe((val) => {
      storage.set('foo', val);
    });
  }

  get observable() {
    return this.fooSubject.asObservable();
  };

  store(val) {
    this.fooSubject.next(val);
  }
}
```

I purposely hide the fact that I'm using a `Subject` with [`.asObservable()`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/Subject.ts#L117) and by wrapping `.next()` call with `store()` method. A typical usage could look like:

```
let settings = new Setting();

settings.store('Hello');

settings.observable.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
settings.store('Hello 2');
settings.store('Hello 3');

settings.observable.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
settings.store('Hello 4');
```

Which prints to console:

```
Hello
Hello 2
Hello 3
Hello 3
Hello 4
Hello 4
```

Note, that you're not initializing the `ReplaySubject` with any value. Even if you called `setting.fooSubject.next(newFoo)` right after creating the `ReplaySubject` it'll be stored again right after subscribing with `storage.set('foo', val);`.

The issue about being synchronous. Well, your code is in fact asynchronous but sequential. Since JavaScript is single threaded then if `storage.get('foo')` does some synchronous time consuming operation then it'll block the execution thread and probably the only option is to move it to a Web Worker.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The objective was to expose `setting.foo` property as a *single* readable/writable property (subject) and not as a pair of getter and setter as it is now (there may be more such properties on `setting`). I'm about to use promises not because `storage` is time consuming but because currently I use sync API (localStorage) and I expect that it will be switched to async (localForage).

Comment: Then I think you can take my version of `Setting` and use it a single item in your `Setting` as `setting.foo` or maybe even better create your own Subject extending `ReplaySubject` :).

Comment: I wasn't really comfortable with subjects and subclassing them, but it appeared to be a very nice idea here, so thank you.